# Why is my UInavigationController right button disappearing after it is loaded

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using the following code to push a view controller when user click on a UIButton

```
- (IBAction)showListPicker:(id)sender {
    if([audioPlayer isPlaying])
    {
        [audioPlayer stop];
    }

    ListPicker *lp = [[ListPicker alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:lp animated:YES];
    [lp release];
}
```

In the ViewDidLoad of ListPicker  I use the following code to add right navigational control button

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    [[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor brownColor]];

    [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]]];

   UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(doSomething:)];

    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:button];

    [button release]; 
}
```

When the view is loaded, I can see the right button briefly but then it disappear right away.  What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Your code is working fine.i think there are some other problem with your remaining code..

Comment: i think you are right.  that code is working on my other view is just not working on this view.

Comment: yes, check in your remaining code.if you found the solution then it's good otherwise post your remaining code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your ListPicker's XIB contains another navigation bar, obstructing the actual navigation controller's bar. This is why you see it for an instant and then it "disappears". If it's not something in the XIB, check the code all the way from instantiating that new view controller until the viewDidAppear of ListPicker.

Comment: ListPicker doesn't have XIB.  it's a subclass of UITableViewController.  What will be the best way to figure out at what event the right button disappear?  There is nothing in ListPicker.m that touch navigational controller other than the viewDidLoad.